# Lifecycle event to detect route changes

Tags: angular, lifecycle

What is the Angular lifecycle event which will fire only when the route is changed? I tried logging with different events but didn't find anything particular to route changes.

Comment: That's not a [component lifecycle hook](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks), they apply to *components*. If you want to hook into router events, see e.g. https://angular.io/guide/router#router-events. The router docs also include various other ways to hook into routing, e.g. resolvers (for ensuring data is available before continuing) and guards (for ensuring the current user is permitted to access the page).

Answer (score 0):

Angular has following life cycle hooks :

- ngOnChanges()
- ngOnInit()
- ngDoCheck()
- ngAfterContentInit()
- ngAfterContentChecked()
- ngAfterViewInit()
- ngAfterViewChecked()
- ngOnDestroy()

Which generally ngOnDestroy() will fire after route change from a component, if you implement it inside the component like:

```
export class xComponent implements OnDestroy {}
```

You better to read [Angular Lifecycle Hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)